# Trying to curl on rancher pod start up but unable to curl

Tags: bash, kubernetes, curl, rancher, busybox

Currently trying to make an init container on rancher which will send a curl to one of my services. I am having repeated issues trying to get this work and I cannot pinpoint why. I am certain my yaml format is correct and I am installing busy box so curl should be available for use

[image: Auto-generated yaml file for side-car]

[image: Error being thrown]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-c` option for the shell to tell it that it should read commands from the command line instead from a file:

```
sh -c curl -X POST ...
```

So you have to put -c as first container arg:

```
...
- args:
  - -c
  - curl
  - -X
...
```